# KendoUI Grid Official Example

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid, editing

I'm referring to this example:

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing

I understand how it is done that price can not be less than `$1`. I understand how it is done that units can be 0 (but not negative).
I understand how this is done in the `HTML5/JavaScript` Version of the example but can't see how it is done in the `ASP.NET/MVC` example. I can't see anything like `Min(1)` for the price Column or `Min(0)` for the `UnitsInStock` Column.
So: How is it done in `ASP.NET MVC`?

Thanks in Advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is keying off the client validation error based on validation attributes placed on the model. The ProductViewModel.cs is not posted in that demo, however, that error_handler() seems to be iterating any errors returned, in which case validation errors would be piped through.